# Kafka Streams - Send on different topics depending on Streams Data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application waiting for records to be published on topic `user_activity`. It will receive json data and depending on the value of against a key I want to push that stream into different topics.

This is my streams App code:

```
KStream<String, String> source_user_activity = builder.stream("user_activity");
        source_user_activity.flatMapValues(new ValueMapper<String, Iterable<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<String> apply(String value) {
                System.out.println("value: " +  value);
                ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    JSONObject send = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject received = new JSONObject(value);

                    send.put("current_date", getCurrentDate().toString());
                    send.put("activity_time", received.get("CreationTime"));
                    send.put("user_id", received.get("UserId"));
                    send.put("operation_type", received.get("Operation"));
                    send.put("app_name", received.get("Workload"));
                    keywords.add(send.toString());
                    // apply regex to value and for each match add it to keywords

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    System.err.println("Unable to convert to json");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return keywords;
            }
        }).to("user_activity_by_date");
```

In this code, I want to check operation type and then depending on that I want to push the streams into the relevant topic.

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have updated my code to this:

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, String> source_o365_user_activity = builder.stream("o365_user_activity");
KStream<String, String>[] branches = source_o365_user_activity.branch( 
      (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"SharingSet") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")),
      (key, value) -> (value.contains("Operation\":\"AddedToSecureLink") && value.contains("ItemType\":\"File")),
      (key, value) -> true
     );

branches[0].to("o365_sharing_set_by_date");
branches[1].to("o365_added_to_secure_link_by_date");
branches[2].to("o365_user_activity_by_date");
```

Comment: Does your updated code works?

Comment: @panoet yes it does

Comment: Thank you. Its saving my time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `branch` method in order to split your stream. This method takes predicates for splitting the source stream into several streams.

The code below is taken from [kafka-streams-examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples):

```
KStream<String, OrderValue>[] forks = ordersWithTotals.branch(
    (id, orderValue) -> orderValue.getValue() >= FRAUD_LIMIT,
    (id, orderValue) -> orderValue.getValue() < FRAUD_LIMIT);

forks[0].mapValues(
    orderValue -> new OrderValidation(orderValue.getOrder().getId(), FRAUD_CHECK, FAIL))
    .to(ORDER_VALIDATIONS.name(), Produced
        .with(ORDER_VALIDATIONS.keySerde(), ORDER_VALIDATIONS.valueSerde()));

forks[1].mapValues(
    orderValue -> new OrderValidation(orderValue.getOrder().getId(), FRAUD_CHECK, PASS))
    .to(ORDER_VALIDATIONS.name(), Produced
  .with(ORDER_VALIDATIONS.keySerde(), ORDER_VALIDATIONS.valueSerde()));
```

Comment: What is `(id, orderValue`)? I was looking at Kafka Streams documentation and its something like `(key, value) -> predicate()`. But I have a Json object in the value and then in that Json object I have multiple keys and values. So how can I branch depending on that?

Comment: This is just an example. Take a look at this: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#branch(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate...)

Ok, I see. The number of predicates is static, so you are able to split the source stream into some predefined number of substreams I guess. If you need some dynamic splitting, you have to redesign the logic, I am afraid.

Regarding your question: you can define a list of predicates like _hasField_(...) or something. Each of the predicates will check if the field in the json.

Comment: Let's say I want to send all the records to the third topic. Does branch allow this?

Comment: @EL323 yes, you just create a predicate evaluating to true for every record.

Comment: Like I have done in my EDIT? But its not getting other logs. Its only getting the logs for which the first two predicates evaluate false.

Comment: @EL323 Ah, I see. I think it's not possible with branch, because the first matching predicate will "catch" the record. I guess, all you need is a branch with two predicates like in your edit. In order to forward all your messages to the third topic I'd just use something like source_o365_user_activity.to(...)

Comment: @codejitsu can we make branches dynamic ? So that we can achieve n num of branches based on a list in db ?

Comment: Since version 2.8 is `KStream.branch(Predicate)` deprecated. Instead `KStream.split().branch(Predicate)` should be used.

Comment: An example with the new version: https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/split-a-stream-of-events-into-substreams/kstreams.html

Answer (score 7):

The original `KStream.branch` method is inconvenient because of mixed arrays and generics, and because it forces one to use 'magic numbers' to extract the right branch from the result (see e.g. [KAFKA-5488](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5488) issue). Starting from [spring-kafka](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) 2.2.4, [KafkaStreamBrancher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/KafkaStreamBrancher.html) class is available. With it, more convenient branching is possible:

```java
        
new KafkaStreamBrancher<String, String>()
    .branch((key, value) -> value.contains("A"), ks->ks.to("A"))
    .branch((key, value) -> value.contains("B"), ks->ks.to("B"))
    .defaultBranch(ks->ks.to("C"))
    .onTopOf(builder.stream("source"))
    //onTopOf returns the provided stream so we can continue with method chaining 
    //and do something more with the original stream
```

There is also [KIP-418](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-418%3A+A+method-chaining+way+to+branch+KStream), so a there is also a chance that branching will be improved in Kafka itself in further releases.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is routing the event dynamically using a *TopicNameExtractor*:

https://www.confluent.io/blog/putting-events-in-their-place-with-dynamic-routing

you would need to have created the topics in advance though,

```
val outputTopic: TopicNameExtractor[String, String] = (_, value: String, _) => defineOutputTopic(value)

builder
  .stream[String, String](inputTopic)
  .to(outputTopic)
```

and *defineOutputTopic* can return one of a defined set of topics given the value (or key or record context for that matter).
PD: sorry for the scala code, in the link there is a Java example.